# Stylish: "Turn all styles off" from command line?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, userscripts, stylish, userstyles

I frequently end up doing ~5 different manual actions when switching between using my laptop in dark environments and light environments, one of which is clicking `Turn all styles off` in the Stylish extension toolbar button to disable my dark user styles.  I'd like to automate this somehow, probably a script bound to a hotkey.  Is there a way to have the same effect as clicking `Turn all styles off` through the command line or some other way to accomplish this goal?  I'm using Stylish in Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Go to Chrome settings, extensions, keyboard shortcuts, Stylish, and assign a hotkey. I'm using Alt-X.

Comment: @wOxxOm I did not know about that, thanks!  Is there any way to "trigger" that from a script or otherwise accomplish the goal above?

Comment: Try googling. What I know is it's easy to send hotkeys on Windows.

Comment: Check out our [Stylish-Toggle](https://github.com/StylishThemes/Stylish-Toggle) userscript. It only works in Chrome.

Comment: @Mottie I don't see from the README at that link how it would help accomplish my goal?

Comment: It shows how to disable styles programmatically from inside the browser regardless of a hotkey.

Comment: Yes, essentially, it uses this selector `style.stylish[id*=stylish]` and disables or enables those stylesheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My findings are that there isn't any way to change chrome extension settings from the command line and that the best way to do this is to set a key binding per [@wOxxOm's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670729/stylish-turn-all-styles-off-from-command-line?noredirect=1#comment66647288_39670729) and to use `xdotool` to send the keystrokes to chrome.  There are a lot of gotchas in getting this to work.  This is the final command I ended up using:

```
xdotool search --class 'google-chrome' windowactivate --sync \
        key --window 0 --clearmodifiers 'ctrl+shift+5'
```

Chrome doesn't accept the keystrokes if it's not active, so use `windowactivate --sync` first.  It seems that Chrome ignores `XTEST` events so use `--window 0` to force `xdotool` to use `XSendEvent` instead.  Finally, I had to use `--clearmodifiers` because I have `Caps_Lock` and `Control_L` swapped.